# How to read a txt file in a .py file and then place the 2nd line of the txt file in the specified position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pynput

I want the numbers in line 2 from the saved.txt file to always be in this position K().type('**022543** ') it is important that there is a space after the numbers.

saved.txt

```
some kind of link
022543
```

load.py

```
import time
import os
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as K

from itertools import islice
with open('saved.txt') as fin:
    for line in islice(fin, 1, 16):
        print(line)

os.startfile("c:\Program Files\Kodi\kodi.exe")
time.sleep(4)
K().type('022543 ')
```

example 2.

```
saved.txt
some kind of link
1849

load.py
K().type('1849 ')
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the string representing the second line - you can either read in all lines from the file with

```
file = open("saved.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
```

and then accessing line 2 with `lines[2]`.
Otherwise you can make use of the linecache module.
See: https://www.codespeedy.com/read-a-specific-line-from-a-text-file-in-python/

After that, it's string concatenation to add a space to the end.

Comment: unfortunately I don't know how the numbers will get here `K().type('1849 ')`

Comment: thanks i solved the space in the txt file it was easier
but how to get it to the right place I still haven't solved

Comment: Do you have a string with the line? Something like `line = lines[2]` as we discussed above? If so can you just use `K.type(line + ' ')`? Unless I'm misunderstanding the question...

Comment: I screwed something up... it works now. 
Thank you very much for your help!

`import time
import os
import webbrowser
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller as K

file = open("saved.txt")
lines = file.readlines()
line = lines[1]

os.startfile("c:\Program Files\Kodi\kodi.exe")
time.sleep(2)
K().type(line + ' ')`